Azure DevOps and Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Script in Synapse REST API sycronize issue

I have a PL_Fetch pipeline with copy data activity for fetching my sql scripts in my azure synapse analytics.
first of all, I made a REST API linked service with the Azure Synapse Workspace I am working on. Then, I created an integration dataset to refer the REST API and wants to fetch the sqlScripts.



in the sink part, I sink the sql script as json into one of my contain in the storage account.
I named it SQLScripts.json


I am confused about the end point section, *how do the rest api know when it mentions endpoint sqlScripts with a proper mapping, then we could fetch all the SQL Script from the azure synapse analytics? *

I wrote Pr_Config_Curated first and then I run the PL_Fetch pipeline. Later, I wrote Pr_Config_Analysis, Pr_Config_Staged, and Pr_Config_Raw and run the PL_Fetch pipeline again. The result of my SQLScripts.json doesn't update. It only has the result for Pr_Config_Curated.

So totally 4 config stored procedure sql scripts in my Azure Synapse Workspace:  Pr_Config_Analysis, Pr_Config_Curated, Pr_Config_Staged, and Pr_Config_Raw. In each script it has a similar content like the code below:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_Config_Analysis](
      @sp_StorageAccount_Analysis NVARCHAR(100)

)
AS

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Schema
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'analysis')
BEGIN
    EXEC('CREATE SCHEMA [analysis] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]');
END


-- External data sources (EDS)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources WHERE name = 'eds_datalake_analysis')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'
        CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE eds_datalake_analysis
        WITH (
            LOCATION = N''https://' + @sp_StorageAccount_Analysis + N'.dfs.core.windows.net/analysis''
            , CREDENTIAL = credential
        )
    '
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END


**Why the SQLScrpts.json doesn't update the sql scripts I create later? How could I solve this? I have done commit all and publish before I run the PL_Fetch pipeline **
2.
After that I create a pipeline PL_Config_Databases in Azure Synapse Workspace config my databases and run the sql scripts.
problem: After I have a linked service connection to the serverless raw database, I could not find my script
Pr_Config_Raw

,
Therefore, I click the Enter manually to refer the stored procedure 
I did the step four times for these four stored procedures, make a commit all, and publish to my Azure DevOps.
After publish, I could see my 4 stored procedure scripts in Azure DevOps, but I only find Pr_Config_Curated in my SQLScripts.json in the container.
If I run the pipeline in Azure Synpase PL_Config_Databases, it will throws me the error
"Operation on target Config Database failed: Operation on target List SQL Scripts in source folder failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Referenced external data source \"eds_datalake_analysis\" From my understanding, it seems like it cannot find the sql script Pr_Config_Analysis for creating the external data source.
Could anyone help me?


how do the rest api know when it mentions endpoint sqlScripts with a proper mapping, then we could fetch all the SQL Script from the azure synapse analytics?

To copy all the SQL scripts from Azure Synapse to Storage account you need to use below Rest API:
https://<Workspace_name>.dev.azuresynapse.net/sqlScripts?api-version=2020-12-01

This Rest API will fetch all the scripts from Synapse workspace on every run.

Why the SQLScrpts.json doesn't update the sql scripts I create later?

You need to publish all the scripts you created on synapse workspace, Rest API can only fetch the published SQL scripts on Synapse Workspace.


I have a linked service connection to the serverless raw database, I could not find my script.

When you add Stored procedure activity in the dropdown of that activity it will only show the existing stored procedures name. So, first you need to create them on your respective database.

Hallo Pratik, I know the rest api link, but my question is how do I know what kind of data/code i could extract from the rest api. In my case, like endpoint, sqlScripts. Is there any documentations to tell my what kind of endpoints I have in the rest api? Secondly, I did create store procedures and then Publish all before I run the PL_Fetch pipeline, but I cannot find those store procedures after that.  Do you mean I have to run the stored procedure script in my database first, like via azure data studio?

Endpoint means your workspace endpoint for example https://your-workspace-name.dev.azuresynapse.net. and sqlScripts is keyword in rest api to fetch all the SQL scripts from that Synapse workspace. if you want only query to be extracted you can use mapping to get perticaular values from  response of rest API.

see this mapping settings return me only query from Rest API output as here

Yes, first you need to run your stored procedure scripts in database then only it will visible in pipeline dropdown

but if I modified the code in my stored procedure, it didn't update. Do I need to run the modified stored procedure in the database beofore I run it in pipeline?

Yes, first you need to run your stored procedure scripts in database

okay, thanks. It works.
